# Python How to replace specified words/characters from a table in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

I have this table in postgres and i want to replace some words/characters.
Hier is the problem. As you can see there are some (::) and extra words.

I want to change the   RIPE::AS-RETN RIPE::AS-RETN6 to AS-RETN AS-RETN6 and ...

```
  ID           AS-SET
+=====+=====================================+
   1  +  RIPE::AS-RETN RIPE::AS-RETN6       +
+=====+=====================================+
   2  +  AS-EASYNET                         +
+=====+=====================================+
   3  +  RIPE                               +
+=====+=====================================+
   4  +  NTTCOM::AS-5713 NTTCOM::AS-5713-ZA +
+=====+=====================================+
```

The results should be

```
  ID           AS-SET
+=====+=====================================+
   1  +  AS-RETN AS-RETN6                   +
+=====+=====================================+
   2  +  AS-EASYNET                         +
+=====+=====================================+
   3  +                                     +
+=====+=====================================+
   4  +  AS-5713 AS-5713-ZA                 +
+=====+=====================================+
```

So it removes the : and the extra spaces and also the word RIPE.
Can Someone can help with this! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `regexp_replace` will do what you want.

Try this (changing the table/column name to suit):

```
SELECT regexp_replace(as_set, '(RIPE::)|(RIPE ?)|(NTTCOM::)', '', 'g')
FROM my_table;
```

and run an update if the result looks good:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET as_set = regexp_replace(as_set, '(RIPE::)|(RIPE ?)|(NTTCOM::)', '', 'g')
```

Comment: how can i remove the , and replace it with space? for example if i have as-TT,asFF.                     To get asTT asFF

Comment: A separate query to replace commas with spaces would look like this: `regexp_replace(as_set, ',', ' ', 'g')`